# Changes to RDLC report in c# project not marking project as out of date

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build, rdlc

I have a c# solution in VS2019 that has multiple projects with references as follows

startup project (A)
classes project (B)
View project (C)

(A) has a reference to (B)
(C) has a reference to (B)

Project (C) holds, among other things, a set of RDLC reports. I have the 'Copy to Output Directory' on the RDLC properties set to 'Copy if newer'.

My understanding of the build process, when I run the solution, the startup project and any referenced projects that have changed should be built. If I make a change to an RDLC report I would expect, on the next run, for project (C) to be built and therefore copy the RDLC to the output directory. This isn't happening. If I re-build the solution everything works but this takes a lot longer due to the solution having 5 projects.

I have tried to research how Visual Studio works out if a project is up-to-date or not but haven't found anything useful.

How can I fix this?

I have tried changing how the projects reference each other but I either break the build order or end up with a circular reference.

Comment: The linker is comparing the executable in the dates of the files in the bin folder with the date of the RDLC file.  Are you creating a Debug or Release package?  My best guess is you are using the debug instead of the release (or opposite) and that is cause of issue.  It may be one of the child project where you have debug and release backward.  I would open the csproj file with notepad and see if you can find out what is wrong.  The csproj is a text file.

Comment: I have check my csproj files and they are all set to Debug. I did find that the target platform was 'Any CPU' on 5 projects and 'x64' on the 5th. I have brought these in line but it still doesn't trigger a build on project (C) when I change an RDLC file. Would it make a difference that the RDLC files are in a sub-folder?

Comment: The RDLC file needs to be a dependency.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-and-remove-project-dependencies?view=vs-2022

Comment: Looking at project dependencies, I can only make a project dependant on another project. You cannot make individual files a dependency. I already have the dependencies set through the project references. (C), which contains the RDLC's is referenced by (B) which is in-turn referenced by (A), my start up project. Is it because it is a 'second level' reference that it isn't being built?

Comment: You may not be able to make the dependencies using the VS tools.  You may need to edit the csproj file with an editor.   Any file should be able to be a dependency.  A dependency is a comparison of the date of the file with date of another file.  I occasionally edit the csproj when the option isn't available in VS.  You can always use the command line compiler instead of compiling in VS.